# using devise WITHOUT the gem, can I simply copy the files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

**Could I simply copy the devise app and lib (and gem?) folders into my respective project folders and have them work just as if I was using the gem?** I'd like to do this so that I can really see all the code, possibly do some customization, and also avoid some "cannot find" errors in my IDE.

**Is this a bad idea?** If this is something that would work would I simply need to remove the gem and copy over the necessary files or would I need to "undo" things that the gem has done. Could this create problems down the road with updates?

Lastly, **how exactly is devise working when I do not have all of the code in my project?** It works when I'm offline so is the code just stored in some secret invisible file or something? Do some gems require an internet connection to retrieve their functionality or **could any gem simply be copied and used in a project without declaring it in the gem file.**

Answer (score 2):

See http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html

*Bundler also allows you to work against a git repository locally instead of using the remote version. This can be achieved by setting up a local override:*

```
bundle config local.GEM_NAME /path/to/local/git/repository
```

Also

http://ryanbigg.com/2013/08/bundler-local-paths/

"*There's a little known feature of Bundler that allows you to use a local Git repository while developing locally, and a remote Git repo when deploying. This feature means that you no longer have to constantly switch between local paths:*"

```
gem 'spree', :path => "~/Projects/gems/spree"
```

And remote paths:

```
gem 'spree', :github => 'spree/spree', :branch => 'master'
```

Comment: just tried the first method with a different gem (community_engine), when I ran that I got the following message, however that folder remains empty. Just to clarify my intent, I want to have all of code the gem uses and copy it into the respective directories in my project so that I can edit it as I choose

Comment: "Your application has set local.community_engine to "/Code/cE". This will override the global value you are currently setting
You are replacing the current global value of local.community_engine, which is currently "/Code/cE""

Comment: Oh wait I think i get it now, that command is meant to be used with the master branch of the gem downloaded and placed in the specified folder, correct? But yea thanks alot for the tip but thats not exactly what I was going for...

Answer (score 1):

Whether this is possible, short answer: Yes. Is this a bad idea? Definitely! In fact, the code is not in your project, but when you install a gem, all its contents will be stored somewhere in your local machine. Therefore, once downloaded, you don't have to be online to use it. Well, though it's not common (and not recommended), you can clone the gem's repository to your project and set the path in the project's Gemfile.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Couple of follow up questions...
Why exactly is it a bad idea...?

And in response to _you can clone the gem's repository to your project and set the path in the project's Gemfile._,
Why would you have to set the path in the projects gem file? If the code is in the project shouldn't it work normally?

Comment: It's simply not the `rails way`. Gems are built with a purpose: reuse of code. You have to set the path in the project's Gemfile because it's a gem project and you want to use it locally. Or you could do as Michael Durrant [suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30745259/561610).