# Convert a rails engine to an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rails-engines

**I would like to take the community_engine source code and change it so that it can be run as a its own application.** The reason I would like to do this is because community_engine contains basically all of the code that my app will use, however much of it needs to be changed or overridden.

I figure that it doesn't make much sense for the app directories sole purpose being either to override a ton of stuff in the engine or to project the engine source that I have modified locally.

I also really want to do this so I will be able to easily see all of the code being used in the app in one place which will make things easier to understand and change.

Heres the community_engine repo: https://github.com/bborn/communityengine

I've asked similar questions as this one in the past but people always seem to think that I just want a to copy the source code to my machine to use locally so hopefully I was better at explaining myself this time:

[using devise WITHOUT the gem, can I simply copy the files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745103/using-devise-without-the-gem-can-i-simply-copy-the-files)

[How to convert a large gem to standalone rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496596/how-to-convert-a-large-gem-to-standalone-rails-app/31496867?noredirect=1#comment50957304_31496867)

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the engine in to `app_root/engines/community_engine` and point the Gemfile to the local path.

```
gem 'community_engine`, path: 'engines/community_engine'
```

The engine code can then be editted directly.